# video upload to google cloud storage using titanium

Tags: file-upload, titanium, google-cloud-storage, appcelerator, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Appcelerator for building apps. I stuck in the situation in which I want to upload recorded video from my app to Google Cloud Storage. We were looking for google cloud storage sdk or modules to use to upload, but we couldn't find much. I've tried several methods as I've researched

Method 1:

```
var dataUri = event.media.nativePath;
Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(dataUri);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
Ti.API.info('onload:- ' + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
};
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
Ti.API.info('onerror:- ' + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
  };
xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
Ti.API.info('math:- ' + Math.floor(e.progress * 100) + "%");
};

xhr.open('GET',
'https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o?’);
xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
   Ti.API.info('math:- ' + Math.floor(e.progress * 100) + "%");
};
xhr.send({ file : dataUri,key:'API KEY' });
```

Response:-

```
   {
   "error": {
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
        "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://cosole.developers.google.com"  
               }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."}
  }
```

Method 2:

```
   var dataUri = event.media.nativePath;
  Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(dataUri);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('onload:- ' + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
  };
  xhr.onerror = function(e) {
     Ti.API.info('onerror:- ' + JSON.stringify(this.responseText));
   };
  xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
     Ti.API.info('math:- ' + Math.floor(e.progress * 100) + "%");
  };
  var REQUEST_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"; 
 xhr.open("GET", REQUEST_URL);
 xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
 Ti.API.info('math:- ' + Math.floor(e.progress * 100) + "%");
};
xhr.send();
```

Response :- devstorage.full_control

Method 3:

```
var dataUri = event.media.nativePath;
Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(dataUri);
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
enableKeepAlive : false
});
xhr.send({ video : dataUri });

xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
xhr.onerror = function(e) {
alert(e.error);
};

xhr.onload = function() {
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
if (data.FILE)
  alert('File: ' + data.FILE);
else
  alert(this.responseText);
};
xhr.open('GET', ‘ipaddress/api_file/api_name’);
xhr.send();
```

Response :-

```
{
    "result": {
    "errno": -4058,
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "syscall": "stat",
    "path": "C:\Sites\Api\test\\file:\\\storage\\emulated\0\Pictures\\test-966434132.mp4"
  },
    "status": 2
}
```

Kindly help me in this situation, I am very new to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I did a search and could not find any libraries written specifically in Titanium for uploading to Google Cloud Storage.

So you basically have 2 options:

The first is to take a native client library (official or one that someone already wrote) and wrap it with Titanium module. You can find client libraries here (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)

The second option is to make calls directly to cloud storage json api yourself. The API documentation could be found here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/ and you would need to implement http calls to it using Titanium code (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient).

For ease of use writing http APIs I recommend using Jason Keen's RESTe library (https://github.com/jasonkneen/RESTe)